# How to use the Bolzano-Weierstrass theorem to prove that a continuous function is bounded on a closed interval？

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

I know how to use the principle of nested intervals to prove it. I also know that the the principle of nested intervals is equivalent to the B-W theorem, but I don't know the answer to the question in the title. I would like to see a proof using the B-W theorem directly.

Comment: It is elementary. Prove it by contradiction.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Real function continuous on closed interval implies it is bounded - over-simple proof??](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/465936/real-function-continuous-on-closed-interval-implies-it-is-bounded-over-simple) (In particular, [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/465987/629362) uses BW)

Answer (score 1):

Let $f: [a, b] \to \mathbb{R}$ be an unbounded function. Then for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$, there exists $x_n \in [a, b]$ such that $|f(x_n) | > n$ (otherwise $f$ would be bounded). Using Bolzano-Weierstrass, we can assume (using a subsequence if needed) without loss of generality that the sequence $(x_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ thus obtained converges to some $x \in [a, b]$. Now, if $f$ were continuous, we would have $$|f(x)| = \lim_{n \to \infty} |f(x_n)| = \infty$$
which is clearly absurd. Therefore unbounded functions defined on closed intervals are never continuous. In other words, a continuous function defined on a closed interval is necessarily bounded, as desired.